# How do you update post meta data in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

can anyone help point me to an example of how to edit post meta data in a Wordpress site, programmed in PHP.

The code to set the meta data is:

```
// Insert the post into the database        
$new_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
update_post_meta( $new_id, 'DetailPageURL', (string)$single_item->DetailPageURL );
```

I would like to be able to edit that afterwards - but I'm not sure how?

Thanks for any advice,

Mark

Comment: You mean like `$_POST['title'] = 'My new title'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you want to be able to update the meta data at a later date, say the following day?

As such, you'd still use update_post_meta(),  but obviously you'd need to enter the content from somewhere - say a form.

For example, if you had the following form

```
<form action='update.php' method='post'>
    <p>Updating the meta data for post ID = 5</p>
    <p>Value: <input type='text' name='value' /></p>
    <p><button type='submit'>Submit</button></p>
</form>
```

Then your update.php would contain:

```
//assuming we are updating post ID = 5
update_post_meta( 5, 'DetailPageURL', $_POST['value'] );
```

Note: you'd probably want to validate the entry etc first, but in principle that's the basics